# How do I populate an array with only non-empty dates

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to capture the earliest date in a series of values and map that into a field within my application.  This works just fine if every field (starting with @CUST) has a valid date value, but throws errors when any of them are blank/invalid.

```
Dim dates() as Date = {[@CUST42FV], [@CUST43FV], [@CUST44FV], [@CUST45FV], [@CUST46FV], [@CUST47FV], 
[@CUST48FV], [@CUST49FV], [@CUST50FV]}
System.Array.Sort(dates)
Dim first As Date = dates(0)
[CX.UW.LASTDATE] = first
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by blank/invalid dates?  As far as I knew the date type couldn't be anything but a valid date

Comment: What type are those badly-named variables? If they are type Date then they can't be "blank" to begin with. If they're not type Date then why are you signing them to elements of a Date array? You should have Option Strict On and it would prevent you from even trying that. Option Strict Off keys you play fast and loose with data types and thus sort of issue is a common result.

Comment: The fields are already Dates, but when empty they default to 01/01/0001 I believe.  I need to be able to exclude those from the array.  Because this is within an existing third-party application, I don't have much control over naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LINQ expression to only select dates that pass TryParse:

```vb
Dim dates() As String = {value1, value2, value3}
Dim orderedValidDates() As DateTime = (From d In dates Where DateTime.TryParse(d.ToString(), Nothing) Order By Date.Parse(d) Select Date.Parse(d)).ToArray()

Dim firstDate As DateTime = orderedValidDates.FirstOrDefault()
Console.WriteLine(firstDate)
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ciRIjx)